# navigator.plugins occasionally not loading Shockwave Flash, interrupting GoogleAnalytics cross-domain

Tags: javascript, plugins, google-analytics, cross-domain, navigator

This is part of a Google Analytics Cross-Domain tracking issue. GA uses fingerprint hash that includes `navigator.plugins` so that if you share a link that includes a `_ga=1221312312315...` parameter you don't continue someone else's session.

If the output from `navigator.plugins` doesn't match between the source and destination domain the link fails.

Now from the research I have done into this already I see no reason why a persons's browser should have different plugins loaded between tabs since it is part of the browser and has nothing to do with the domain you're on.

However for some reason this plugin is sometimes not loaded on my source domain but always loaded on the destination domain.

```
Plugin {0: MimeType, 1: MimeType, name: "Shockwave Flash", filename: "pepflashplayer.dll", description: "Shockwave Flash 25.0 r0", length: 2}
```

I say sometimes because sometimes it is is loaded and sometimes it isn't. I've tested in Chrome 58, normal, incognito, Firefox, IE, Edge and also in a staging version of the sites this is happening on.

This happens intermittently on various client sites I deal with. One case in particular, when I load the dev site I don't have the shockwave plugin loaded, but when I got to the live site (same tab, new or incognito doesn't matter) `navigator.plugins` has shockwave loaded. The two sites are identical in terms of their source.

Another case the live site doesn't have it loaded, but dev and destination domain have it loaded.

Has anyone experienced this issue or have any idea on how to make sure that plugin is loaded?

EDIT:

I should mention that this is independent of whether the site has any flash content on it or not.